# Must the largest independent set of a graph contain a vertex of minimum degree?

Tags: graph-theory

> Must the largest independent set of a graph contain a vertex of minimum degree?

My gut feeling is yes, but I can't think of a substantive reason as to why. Does a proof for this exist, or is this premise false?

Comment: The question itself is good, but you could improve your post by including context.

Comment: Do you mean *every* maximum independent set? I think that might not be true. But, if true, would be an interesting result.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following graph[image]

The maximum independent set size of this graph is three, since an independent set can contain at most one of A and B, of D and E, and of C, F and G. The set {B, F, D} is a maximum independent set without any vertices of minimal degree.

Edit: I saw Bof's answer and realized it's better than mine, since for this example, there are no maximum independent sets that contain vertices of minimal degree. Here is a picture of Bof's solution.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's a very simple example that I didn't think of.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a graph in which ***no*** largest independent set contains a vertex of minimum degree.

The graph $G$ has $7$ vertices $t,u,v,w,x,y,z$ and $14$ edges; namely, there are edges joining the vertices $x,y,z$ to one another; edges joining each of the vertices $u,v,w$ to each of the vertices $x,y,z;$ and edges $tu,tv.$ The minimum degree is $2,$ and the independence number is $3.$ The vertex $t$ is the only vertex of degree $2,$ and the set $\{u,v,w\}$ is the only independent set of cardinality $3.$

Comment: Interesting construction

Comment: Great solution - the original question was ambiguous, but this counterexample covers both interpretations.